# Where is the session data stored if no cookies are set?

Tags: node.js, session, puppeteer, telegram

## Scenario

I want to login to the web software of Telegram https://web.telegram.org with Node using puppeteer. The strange thing is that no cookies are saved. Neither in the browser nor in puppeteer. Telegram seems to save the session somewhere else.

## What I tried

Despite saving the cookies which I normally do and works, I also tried saving the local storage. Although my puppeteer code worked it did not restore the session where I am logged in. So this does not seem to be the place where the session is stored too.

## Question

Where does the Telegram web version save the session? I will attach some screenshots which may help you so that you do not need to log in and see yourself.

## Screenshots

This is everything what Firefox shows me.
[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]
[image: Screenshot 4]
[image: Screenshot 5]
[image: Screenshot 6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption was right that it is the local storage. Something went wrong in my code and I assume that I saved the local storage before it was completely loaded.